# How to get keys pressed before enter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this question has already been asked, I am trying to create an app where the user scans a bar code and the data is then shown on the screen. I don't want to use textbox's because I don't want the data to be editable.

So far I've managed to get the enter key which is automatically sent at the end of the barcode but can't seem to get the keys pressed before, any help would be massively appreciated!

```
var item = "";
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    alert(item);
  }else{
    item  = item + e.which();
  }
});
```

Just to clarify what I want to do is show an alert box with the keys pressed before enter! For example : A B C D ENTER would show an alert("ABCD")

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So got my code to work but I'm getting "undefinedTHEKEYSPRESEDHERE" as the return:

```
var counter = 0;
var item = [];
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    alert(item[counter]);
    counter++;
  }else{
    item[counter] = item[counter] + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  }
});
```

Obviously this isn't clear enough, so I've outlined my problem below:

What I'm getting from alert(item[counter]);:

```
undefinedKEYS
```

What I want from alert(item[counter]);:

```
KEYS
```

So from undefinedKEYS to just KEYS I need to remove the text "undefined".

Clear enough?

Comment: Fixed sorry mistyped when posting, still have the issue as previously stated

Comment: just make your `item` an array and push to it the key whenever it's **not** `13` and if so, empty the array and start again.

Comment: You have suddenly taken two different answers and combined them. You are treating the string as an array in the second example. :) What is the purpose of your counter?

Comment: There is X amount of fields, the seperation of fields is denoted by the enter key :P, try to view my pseudo code from a PHP dev's POV

Comment: You need to push items onto an array. Otherwise you get undefined elements using[]. Still not sure of your aim though. Best you updated the question to explain the full situation :)

Comment: Finding it difficult to expand on what I've previously posted. Maybe I need to make it clear I'm getting the literal alert box saying "undefinedThen the keys" I just want it to say "Then the keys" :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `e.which()` to `String.fromCharCode(e.which)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8msksn3a/

```
var item = "";
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    alert(item);
  }else{
    item  = item + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  }
});
```

Comment: Curt, don't suppose you could tell me how to fix my additional problem (sorry JS really is my weakpoint) will just update the original post

Comment: @JaviQualmsPdog What are you trying to do? Why is it an array? You should add to an array instead of concatenate `item.push( String.fromCharCode(e.which));`

Comment: I'm trying to get 3 strings into the array (which it is doing fine all apart from the fact each item is getting prefixed with "undefined")

Comment: Accepting this as it helped the most, ended up having to use substr(9) which was messy to remove the undefined at the start of my strings, thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

1. Not that I recommend this way of checking for previous results, but you are basically resetting item to "" inside the keypress event. Set it once outside the event.
2. `which` is a property, not a method:
3. Convert from ASCII to string char with `string.fromCharCode` (A google search would have given you that in two seconds).
4. Use `(e.which || e.keyCode)` to ensure you get the keycode on all browsers.

e.g.

```
var item = "";
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if((e.which || e.keyCode) == 13) {
    alert(item);
  }else{
    item  = item + String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste to your console and run:

```
var keys = [];
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var keyChar;
  if(e.which == 13) {
    console.log( keys.join('') );
    keys.length = 0;
  }
  else{
    keyChar = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if( keyChar )
      keys.push( keyChar );
  }
});
```

This technique will not show keys which does not have a textual character assigned to them (like the F1-F12 keys for example)